# find the range of $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2−9}$

Tags: functions

$$f(x)=\sqrt{x^2−9}$$
I know that the domain of square root is greater than or equal to zero. I solve for when $x^2−9\ge 0$ and get $x^2\ge9$. Now I get $x\ge 3$ and x≤−3. So that the domain would be (−∞,−3]∪[3,∞).

But how can i find its range? Would anybody please show me the process of find the range of $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2−9}$.

Comment: By "x2-9" did you mean $x^2-9$? Also, you should have gotten "$x \le -3$ or $x \ge 3$" instead of "x>−3 and x>3".

Comment: You are right. I mistook to write the right domain... It should  be x<=-3 instead of x>3

Answer (score 1):

In $\mathcal D =(- \infty, -3] \cup [3, +\infty)$, the range of $x \rightarrow x^2-9$ is $[0, +\infty)$.

> This is because :
>
> - $\forall x \in \mathcal D, x^2-9 \ge 0 $
> - $\exists x \in \mathcal D, x^2-9 = 0 $. Indeed, $3$ and $-3$ work
> - $x \rightarrow x^2-9$ is continuous on $[3, +\infty)$, as well as on $(- \infty, -3]$, and $\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}x^2-9 = +\infty$

Furthermore, $\sqrt{[0, +\infty)} = [0, +\infty)$

Then the range is $[0, +\infty)$

Comment: Glad to hear that ! You haven't accepted one of the answers yet, you should do it so that the topic will be marked as resolved

Answer (score 1):

Let's investigate what happens on the interval $[3,+\infty)$. We note that the function $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2-9}$ is symmetric around $x=0$, so we can justify not needing to look at the cases when $x\in(-\infty,-3]$ to find the range.

For $x\in[3,+\infty)$, we have the following:

- $f(x)$ is a (strictly increasing) **continuous** function on this interval
- $f(3)=0$
- $f(x)\rightarrow +\infty$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$

Thus we can conclude that the range for $f(x)$ will be all nonnegative real numbers, namely the interval $[0,+\infty)$